# count the number in each cell from a column (Single digit in a cell or separated by comma)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

In the above image I have two columns (leave the headers with percentage):

In this column I want to know the numbers frequently appeared in 'n' of times in each column.

For example, In first column 6 appeared two times and 3 appeared a single time.( I want all numbers) As well as second column also.

Without comma separation I can able to get the values for example of *3*

```
 =COUNTIF(J3:J11,3)*60 (60 is header portion)
 The result is 1*60 = 60 (3 number appeared in a single time)
```

With comma separation I couldn't find any solution.

Could you please someone help me on this one.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show your desired results too? Not just for that 1*60 situation.

Comment: Excel version? Windows or Mac?

Comment: Windows 10 Ms-Office 2016

Comment: @jvdv: 6 is the target for example '6' appeared two times in the column.      Required script is =COUNTIF(J3:J11,6)*60 (60 is header portion) = 2*60 = 120 is the required output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure if this is in the right direction, but try:

[image]

Formula in `C2`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(FIND(","&C1&",",","&A2:A10&",")))*A1
```